# Forcing static variable initialization at runtime

Tags: java

Is there a way to ensure that a class's static initialization is performed at runtime, and not on the first access of said class?

I am asking because I am currently using a library(of useful tools across multiple projects) but some of them take a reasonable amount of time to initialize. This leads to noticeable lag on the first access of said class, which is not good.

I do understand I can manually initialize it by adding a static method that I call myself at runtime, which does nothing, to force initialize that class, but if there is something I can do to ensure it will be initialized without manually calling an initialization method, that would be much better.

This is what I mean:

Utility Class:

```
public class Utility {
    public static final Map mapping = new HashMap();
    static {
        //Read file and fill in mappings
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
public class Main {
    public void main(String[] args){
        //
        //Do things for a while
        //

        Object something = 
           Utility.mapping.get("else"); //Lag spike occurs here as the
                                        //static initialization was
                                        //only just now run
    }
}
```

This is what I currently do to force it, but requires me to call it manually:

Utility Class:

```
public class Utility {
    public static final Map mapping = new HashMap();
    static {
        //Read file and fill in mappings
    }

    public static void init(){}
}
```

Main Class:

```
public class Main {
    public void main(String[] args){
        Utility.init();     //Lag occurs here, where it belongs
        //
        //Do things for a while
        //

        Object something = 
           Utility.mapping.get("else"); //No lag spike now
    }
}
```

Comment: `performed at runtime` - how runtime is different from "first access"?

Comment: @Lashane The loading would occur first, and not in the middle of workflow when it can be noticed.

Comment: so, prolonged start of the application will not be noticed?

Comment: Yeah, you can just access the class once right at start up and it will look like part of the normal start up of the app.  Though normally I think lazy initialization is better.  I'm curious now: how *exactly* is the lag noticeable?  Because there might be things you can actually do here rather than shift the lag to the start-up time.

Comment: Correct, or at the very least, would be better than having a lag spike at some undetermined moment later when it is first accessed.

Comment: @markspace Some things just take a long time to do, which is why they are contained in a separate library and shared between projects. I currently just use an empty static function named 'init' to force the stuff to load, but it always bothered me that I had to do that, as if I was missing something that should make it unnecessary.

Comment: I've seen the use of an "init" function before too.  I think it's the only way in Java.  The Java spec guarantees classes will not be loaded and/or initialized *until* it is accessed by your program.  Thus, no pre-loading is possible, afaik.

Comment: You could use package scanning to solve this. Ewww....

Comment: I might as well mention: I was thinking that if there's a noticeable pause in a GUI (for example) the usual technique is to spawn a background thread so that there's no noticeable "glitch" or pause in the GUI responsiveness.  Won't work in all situations but might help the user "feel" there there's less of a noticeable lag.

Comment: Speaking of "a better way", how big is the file you are loading?  Is there any way to speed the file IO up?  Don't load so much at one time?

Comment: @markspace I appreciate the input, but that isn't actually the question I was asking and isn't relevant. Whether I can or cannot speed it up isn't what I was wanting an answer for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways:

1. The simple way is to ensure that the real "first access" happens during initialization.  It could be as simple as calling some dummy static method of the class to be initialized in your `main(...)` method.
2. A slightly more sophisticated way to do it would be to have a list of  class name strings that you want to force initialize, and use [`Class.forName(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-) to load each one.  (Note that this overload will force initialization.)

   The advantage of this approach is that your `main` doesn't need to depend on the APIs of the classes you are loading.

   Note that the name must be  in the format returned by [`Class.getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--).   For a reference type that is not an array type, this is fully-qualified name as you would typically write it in Java source code.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, I'd forgotten that `Class.forName()` will also initialize a class file.  Overall though I feel it might be better for the OP to just accept the lag, or maybe come up with a better (faster) way to initialize the class rather than apparently trying to load everything all at once.

Comment: @markspace - that is his decision.  It depends on the nature of the application, including whether the initialization time is significant, and how much user impact the lags really have on the "user experience".

Comment: @StephenC This is great info, I didn't realize you could initialize that way.

Answer (score 0):

Static blocks will get executed only when **classes** are loaded by the **CLASS LOADERS** and it requires the reference of the class. As you are referencing your **Utility** class for the first time in between the workflow, then it will be loaded at that moment and only then static variables got initialized.

If you have some kind of **splash screens** or any **loading page** which gets called for the first time when your application starts up then you can use below to initialize your class `Class.forName("Utility")`. Now your static variables are initialized on next use.